# Passing a dictionary to a behavior

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, behavior, attachedbehaviors

I have a simple Behavior like that

```
public class KeyBoardChangeBehavior : Behavior<UserControl>
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> DataToCheckAgainst; 


    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown += _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
    }


        void _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // My business will go there 
    }

}
```

I want to asign value to this dictionary from the view , I call it as following

```
<UserControl x:Class="newhope2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:Interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:newhope2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Behaviors:KeyBoardChangeBehavior  />
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but how can I pass this dictionary to the behavior from XAML or its code behind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take a Binding, a property needs to be a `DependencyProperty`.

You need to define the property, in the Behaviour, like so:

```
    public Dictionary<string, int> DataToCheckAgainst
    {
        get { return (Dictionary<string, int>)GetValue(DataToCheckAgainstProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataToCheckAgainstProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataToCheckAgainstProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DataToCheckAgainst",
            typeof(Dictionary<string, int>),
            typeof(KeyBoardChangeBehavior),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Use the Visual Studio "propdp" snippet.

Usage is as Adi said, like so:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:KeyBoardChangeBehavior DataToCheckAgainst="{Binding MyDictionary}" />
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: thanks, what if I want to pass with the same way the text of the textbox

Comment: You'd need to add another dependency property of string, and then either bind to the same property the text box is binding to, or, if the text box isn't binding to anything, bind directly to the text box using an ElementName binding. I suggest reading through the docs on binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: how to define this dictionary on XAML please

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is declare the dictionary as a property and then pass it a value via binding.

In the behavior:

```
public Dictionary<string, int> DataToCheckAgainst { get; set; }
```

In XAML:

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:KeyBoardChangeBehavior DataToCheckAgainst="{Binding MyDictionary}" />
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: I forgot to use a Dependency Property instead of a normal property for the binding to work. @Duncan's solution is the way to go.

Comment: thanks, what if I want to pass with the same way the text of the textbox

Comment: I'm not sure what textbox you're referring to, but you could just change the binding so it binds to the textbox (either by using ElementName or RelativeSource).